# the type of variable returned by ''theano.tensor.cast''

Tags: python, theano

What is the exact type of a variable returned by `theano.tensor.cast` when the input is a shared variable?

For example, execute the following code:

```
import theano.tensor as T
from theano import function, shared
import numpy as np

x = shared(np.array([1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4, 5.5], dtype = np.float64))
y = T.cast(x, 'int32')
print type(x)     # <class 'theano.tensor.sharedvar.TensorSharedVariable'>
print type(y)     # <class 'theano.tensor.var.TensorVariable'>

'''
however, the variable y has value like "shared variable"
'''

f = function([], y[:3])
print f()            # it shows ''[1 2 3]''
```

So.... what is the type of variable `y`?

Comment: use `print type(y)` to know its type

Comment: I know it, the result of "type(y)" is that y is a TensorVariable, but the variable y has value as the above code shows.

Comment: it should be a `TensorVariable`, I don't quite understand what do you mean by "the variable y has value like shared variable"?